# Makefile Target: Difference between %.o and $(OBJ)

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

What is the difference between these two targets:

`%.o : %.cpp
       $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@`

and

`$(OBJ) : $(SRC)
          $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@`

If we assume that `SRC` contains all the .cpp files present in the directory and `OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first specifies that each object file depends on its corresponding source file, and defines a reasonably sensible rule to make the object file (`$@`, the first target) from the source file (`$^`, all the dependencies). It should use `$<`, just the first dependency, since there will usually be other dependencies - headers included by the source file. You can often leave this rule out altogether; there's an [implicit rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules) for compiling a single C++ file.

The second specifies that all the object files depend on all the source files, and defines a dysfunctional rule which will fail to compile anything. For example, defining `SRC = a.cpp b.cpp`, this expands to

```
g++ -c  a.cpp b.cpp -o a.o
```

which fails since `-c` only compiles a single source file:

```
g++: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
```

Comment: What if there are other .cpp files that are not supposed to be compiled by the above target? e.g. `ls` gives `a.cpp b.cpp` but `SRC = a.cpp` only

Comment: @rawcoder: They'll only be compiled if the final target you're building depends on them. For example, if you're building a program that depends on `a.o` but not `b.o`, then only `a.cpp` will be compiled.

Comment: if the final target depends on $(OBJ) and $(SRC) contains only a.cpp the final target could not be build. But remember, the rule `$(OBJ):$(SRC)` with OBJ=a.o b.o and SRC=a.c b.c makes no sense! That say: a.o depends on a.c AND!!! b.c and also b.o depends on a.c AND b.c So I think $(SRC) should not contain the source files itself.

Comment: Coming back again to the gives example: The second rule from OP is logical invalid in the given context. And the recipe will only compile the first prerequisite what is also not is, what I would expect. So I think it is important, that OP knows what the `SRC=list of sources` will do!

Answer (score 0):

`$(SRC)` did NOT contain all source files! It contains a rule, how the source file name can be build from the object file name.

If `$(SRC)` contains all source files like a.c and b.c and $(OBJ) contains a.o and b.o the rule expands to:

```
a.o b.o: a.c b.c
```

which is not valid!

The difference:

`$(OBJ)` contains typically a list of needed object. So the rule knows which objects must be build. Make will call the compiler for all the source file and build the objects.

The first rule is only a rule which will actually do nothing without any other `trigger` for that.

If you complete your example to:

```
 %.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

do: x.o y.o
    $(CXX) -o do x.o y.o
```

make knows that x.o and y.o are needed for `do`. So he look for a rule to build them and catch your first rule.

But your first rule must not be defined manually, it normally exist already. For all implicit rules take a look at:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: "`$(SRC)` did NOT contain all source files!" - how do you know? The question says it does, and doesn't show a definition to contradict that claim.

Comment: If $(SRC) contain all src-files, the rule is broken! It is not possible to write a n:m rule! So I `believe` that this is simply not given :-)

Comment: Indeed, the second rule would be broken in that case. Perhaps your answer should explain that, rather than making a strange claim that `$(SRC)` is something other than what it's stated to be.

Comment: `a.o b.o: a.c b.c` is valid: you can specify multiple targets with multiple dependencies (You wouldn't want to here, since `a.o` doesn't depend on `b.c`, but that doesn't invalidate the concept). It's the recipe, attempting to compile multiple source files in a single command, that's invalid.

Comment: Yes, it is valid to Make but makes no sense in this example. And I believe that this was not given. But you are right, that is *my* expectation.